# Not able to install setuptools on linux mint

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, setuptools, linux-mint

I used this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

it throws up an error instead of installing - 
Package 'python-setuptools' has no installation candidate

Comment: *If you have Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >= 3.4 installed from python.org, you will already have pip and setuptools*... The Python Documentation

Comment: @cricket_007 I have python 2.7.6

Comment: Via your system, sure. You're welcome to install additional pythons. What do you need setuptools for?

Comment: Try this: https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/python-setuptools

Comment: @cricket_007 i want to install tensorflow for deeplearning for that i need pip and setuptoolls installed

Comment: Okay, so what's preventing you from getting Python3? Any new development should be done in it anyway

Comment: If you actually need Pip and setuptools for the OS python, I recommend you use the get-pip installer  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't know how to install python3 on top of python2 I am using

Comment: Try running `python3`. It might already be installed

Comment: Alternatively, the answers are out there if you search. https://mintguide.org/other/794-python-3-6-install-latest-version-into-linux-mint.html

Comment: shows malformed line error while installing 3.6 @cricket_007

Comment: So, it's not already installed? According to the post, 3.5 is there in the latest Mint version

Comment: @cricket_007 3.4 is installed. need to install pip and setuptools for that

Comment: Are you sure? `pip3` might be installed too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is a python package so you could use pip to install it

```
pip3 install setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

When pip is installed type in:

```
pip install setuptools
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unable to locate package python-pip

Comment: Try: sudo apt install python-pip

Comment: If that doesn't work try typing: sudo apt-get update

Comment: @Yasheel You messed up the apt sources file, then https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list